# android firebase push notification

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

after struggling with it for two days I have no clue what to do so I am asking in here...

I used the simplest way to make push notification with android and firebase.
I installed the firebase engine, did a simple test on the android emulator with nexus 4 on my pc, all worked well, I got an instance ID, I was able to see notifications, all was good.

after an hour or something, for some reason I stopped getting new instance IDs (tokens) for some reason.

These are the logs I am getting:

`D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getNoBackupFilesDir, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.util.zzx.getNoBackupFilesDir
D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.zze.zzm
I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful`

I saw in some places that I need to make sure my emulator is updated so I think I updated it good, but still I got nothing now.
the weird thing is that I am able to get notifications, but(!) I don't get tokens any more...

I am using two services classes, one is to generate new tokens (which doesn't seems to work) and one to recieve the notifications (which seems to work fine).

THIS IS TO GENERATE TOKENS:

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {

    //Getting registration token
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

    //Displaying token on logcat
    //Toast.makeText(MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.this, "testt", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
    //sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
}
```

THIS IS TO RECIEVE NOTIFICATIONS:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        //Displaying data in log
        //It is optional
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        //Calling method to generate notification
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    //This method is only generating push notification
    //It is same as we did in earlier posts
    private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("title")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

THESE ARE THE GRADLE FILES:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app id"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.2"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and the main gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

THIS IS THE MANIFEST (the relevant parts):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="package name..."
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="1.2">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme"
        >

        <activity
            ...
        </activity>
        <!--
        tools:node="merge"
             ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
             App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        -->

        <!--
        Defining Services
        -->
        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

any help please?

Comment: You repeatedly say that you don't get a token anymore. But keep in mind that `onTokenRefresh()` will not be called every time you run the app. It will only be called when the token changes, which happens very infrequently. Since your code doesn't do anything in `onTokenRefresh()` it is also very unlikely the cause of the problem, so I wouldn't worry about that part. How do you send the notifications?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen wow thanks a lot u r right. I uninstalled the app, and the installed it again and I got new token, I am sendng the notifications through Firebase. you said that sometimes the tokens do get refreshed, is there a way of checking when, and then updating the database or something?

Comment: If the token gets refreshed, your `onTokenRefresh()` will be called. I typically handle persisting tokens in my main activity's `onCreate` and in `onTokenRefresh` to capture both the initial value and the refresh.

Comment: I have almost same configuration and I get "Could not find method android.content.Context.isDeviceProtectedStorage, referenced from method com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza"
Also is confusing. At the final it says: "D/FirebaseInstanceId: topic sync succeeded" but I try to send a message from Firebase console and does not reach my device